# How to execute a shell script through python

Tags: python, shell, subprocess, popen

I have a script say abc.sh which has list of commands with flags.
example

```
//abc.sh
echo $FLAG_name
cp   $FLAG_file1   $FLAG_file2
echo 'file copied'
```

I want to execute this script through python code.
say

```
//xyz.py

name = 'FUnCOder'
filename1  = 'aaa.txt'
filename2 = 'bbb.txt'

subprocess.call([abc.sh, name, filename1, filname2], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, shell=True)
```

This call is not working.

What are the other options?

Also the shell script file is in some other directory. And I want the output to go in logs.

Comment: have you considered using [shutls](http://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html) instead of a bash script. Try `shutils.copyfile`

Comment: Using `shell=True` here is wrong and bug-inducing.

Answer (score 3):

Usually you want to use [`Popen`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor) since you have process control afterwards. Try:

```
import subprocess
process = subprocess.Popen(['abc.sh', name, filename1, filname2], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
process.wait() # Wait for process to complete.

# iterate on the stdout line by line
for line in process.stdout.readlines():
    print(line)
```

Comment: I tried this but couldn't get any output on screen... Can you explain a little about redirecting to PIPE and not STDOUT?

Comment: By redirecting to PIPE you can read the stdout of your script by using `process.stdout.readlines()` or `process.stdout.read()` etc.

Comment: I think it's also the only alternative since he wants to log the output.

Comment: it worked but the script is not taking any arguments that I'm passing. what could be the problem?

Comment: If you are using the same script as the one on your original question, then you are doing it wrong. Shell scripts arguments are passed as `$1 $2 $3` etc.

Comment: you mean i have to pass it as

Comment: process = subprocess.Popen([abc.sh, $1=name, $2=filename1, $3=filname2], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)

Comment: got it..... I have to mix it the command like I fire on shell.....cool thanks....

Also One more ques.... Can I redirect the stdout to a file....say log?

Comment: @Alex You copied the original version's mistake of not quoting `abc.sh` as a string (`"abc.sh"`).

Comment: @RishabhAgarwal No, not `$1=...` in the Python -- but they show up as `$1`, `$2`, and so forth on the shell side. Where did you ever get the idea that they were called things like `FLAG_file1`? How would the shell know that the argument was a file, and name its variable automatically?

Comment: Thanks Charles... I was just looking for an abstract answer. Will take care of the flag format... 
Thanks everyone

Comment: @Alex using `wait()` before reading from `process.stdout()` can hang forever if the amount of output is larger than the buffer. Safer to use `process.communicate()` in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
//xyz.py

name = 'FUnCOder'
filename1  = 'aaa.txt'
filename2 = 'bbb.txt'

process = subprocess.Popen(['abc.sh', name, filename1, filname2], stdout=PIPE)
process.wait()
```

Notice that 'abc.sh' is in quotes because it's not a variable name, but the command you're calling.

I would also, in general, recommend using `shell=False`, though in some cases it is necessary to use `shell=True`.

To put output into a file try:

```
with open("logfile.log") as file:
    file.writelines(process.stdout)
```

Comment: Try running it without the PIPEs

Comment: i printed the retcode of this call and its says 0...which mean its failing... any idea why?

Comment: return code 0 means it's not failing, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status#POSIX.

Comment: Lolz...I referred this http://support.leadtools.com/CS/forums/27479/ShowPost.aspx

Comment: @RishabhAgarwal Don't trust everything you read on the web. The wikipedia reference is correct.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a old question, below is the way if you are using Python 3.5 & above versions.

```
import subprocess
process = subprocess.run('script.sh', shell=True, check=True, timeout=10)
```

**Ref:** https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run

Answer (score 0):

I am on macOS and to run a shell script I used:

`process = subprocess.Popen([abc.sh, name, filename1, filname2], shell=True)`