# Running .sh file from Python script?

Tags: python, linux, popen, python-3.3

I am having trouble running a `.sh` script in Oracle Linux 6.8 using a python script I have developed. I've developed these scripts in Windows OS and they run without a problem, now I am trying to modify these scripts to run them on Linux but I am having problems since I am not familiar with Linux OS.

I run a `.bat` file in Windows using the `Popen` command in python, for example: 
`p = Popen("StartScript.bat", cwd=r"My path")`

Where `StartScript.bat` is the `.bat` file, and `My Path` is the path where the `.bat` file is located. This works very good in Windows OS, but how do I do the same for Linux OS, if I want to run a `StartScript.sh` file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[execute a shell-script from Python subprocess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16855642/execute-a-shell-script-from-python-subprocess)

[How to execute a shell script through python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16180414/how-to-execute-a-shell-script-through-python)

Please take a look at these two threads. Hope it helps.

Comment: Gaurav Pathak, according to the links you have provided, there is no need to enter a path (where the .sh file is located) to execute the .sh file when using Popen? Is this right?

Comment: @viganqerimi
You need to provide the path of the shell script.

If `Popen("StartScript.bat", cwd=r"My path")` is not working for you. May I know the error that you are gettting?

Comment: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'start_stageconv.sh'

Comment: What I need is the equivalent of my popen command that I have used in Windows OS, but for LINUX OS. 

So I can execute my .sh script using python.

Is this going to work: p = Popen(['./start_stageconv.sh'], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)

Comment: @viganqerimi
Use `p = Popen(["sh", "./start_stageconv.sh"], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)`
You can also provide the path of the shell script instead of ./start_stageconv.sh if you don't want to put your python script in the same directory also I suggest to check the presence of file using os.path.exists() before passing it to subprocess.Popen()

Comment: Where do I have to write the path? 

Will this work
p = Popen(["sh", "/u01/app/Oracle_ODI_11/oracledi/agent/bin/start_stageconv.sh"], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)

Comment: Yes, that should work. Or try using cwd parameter of subprocess.

Answer (score 4):

use this lines:

```
import os
os.popen('sh command')
```

for example

```
import os
os.popen('sh /home/oracle/scripts/start.sh')
```

enjoy

Comment: how to pass arguments?